# Reusing requests_oauthlib authorisation

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, python-requests, authorization

I'm trying to get data from my thermostat API using requests_oauthlib. The API uses OAuth 2. I've successfully fetched the first chunk of data, and would like to do more. However, at the moment, my program repeats the authorization dialogue on each run. I am probably missing something in the documentation, but could I reuse the received `session.authorization_token`  (until user revokes authorization on the thermostat web-site)?

The program looks like this:

```
import json
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session

client_id = r'api-XXXX'
client_secret = r'YYYY'

authorization_base_url = 'https://api.thermosmart.com/oauth2/authorize'
token_url = 'https://api.thermosmart.com/oauth2/token'
redirect_uri = 'https://google.com/'

session = OAuth2Session(client_id, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)

authorization_url, state = session.authorization_url(authorization_base_url)
print('Please go here and authorize: ', authorization_url)

# Get the authorization verifier code from the callback url
redirect_response = input('Paste the full redirect URL here and add a trailing space: ')
redirect_response = redirect_response[0:-1]  # prevent PyCharm from opening URL

# Fetch the access token
session.fetch_token(token_url, client_secret=client_secret,
                    authorization_response=redirect_response)

# Fetch a protected resource
r = session.get('https://api.thermosmart.com/thermostat')
if not r.status_code == 200:
    print("Not OK received")
else:
    thermostat_id = json.loads(r.content).get('hw')
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save and reuse the token, but they will eventually expire. You'll need to configure a method of refreshing the token. See: http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2_workflow.html#refreshing-tokens

To answer your question regarding how to reuse it, just do this:

```
new_session = OAuth2Session(client_id, token=variable_where_token_was_stored)
new_session.get('https://api.thermosmart.com/thermostat')
```

Comment: How do I reused the token? I was searching exactly for this. I can access it via session.access_token, so I can save it, but how do I re-create the session with that token?